# Include dump of child processes when running procdump

Tags: procdump

Is there a procdump option such that when you run procdump on a process P it also takes a dump of all the child processes of process P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was no. I ended up writing a wrapper for procdump to take dumps of the child processes

Comment: Any chance you could provide more info on this? I would find it really useful! Thanks.